# async/wait loop with readline (inquirer) questions

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

I am using Inquirer & Typescript 2.3 for a console application, here's whats goind down

- I want to have the user pick a name from the lists using await. No problem
- Afterwards, i want the user to pick 1 or more options that he would like to adjust. No problem
- I want to loop trough all the chosen option, using the same async/await as before.
- I want to fill up the `answers` object like `{fieldName: chosenOption, fieldname2: chosenOption2}`

But that's where i get into trouble. I have tried various options, but whatever kind of loop i use, I end up with getting all * qeuestions to answer and have them the same value.

I see this is a subject widely explained, but i am simply overlooking something obvious. In order not to take up space the [`this.ask`](https://gist.github.com/RobinRadic/fd744177d7a1e4dcff2b594e189ed191) class property is included as gist.

```
async startInteractive() {
    let names = Object.keys(this.config('connect'));
    let name  = await this.ask.list('name', names);
    console.log('need to edit ', name);
    let availableFields       = [ 'user', 'host', 'port', 'method', 'localPath', 'hostPath' ]
    let chosenFields: Answers = await this.ask.checkbox('Choose fields to edit', availableFields)
    let current               = this.config('connect.' + name);

    let answers = {}

    // THIS PART
    // is the issue i'm not able to tackle
    await chosenFields.map(async (field) => {
        answers[ field ] = await this.ask.ask(field)
    })
}
```

Edit: this is the visual representation of the problem:

- [image: enter image asdfasdfenter code here here]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in your `InputHelper` methods (all of them)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chosenFields.map` will return an array of callback results, i.e. promises in the case of the `async` callback. To be able to `await` an array of promises, you need to use `Promise.all` to convert it into a promise for an array before:

```
await Promise.all(chosenFields.map(async (field) => {
    answers[ field ] = await this.ask.ask(field)
}))
```

---

I can't tell why you'd get the same result for all fields, though. It seems there's a race condition in `inquirer.prompt` when it is called concurrently. To invoke it sequentially, use

```
for (let field of chosenFields) {
    answers[ field ] = await this.ask.ask(field)
}
```

Comment: Had to invoke it sequentually indeed. many thanks. I'll go and read up on that Promise constructor antripatern as well. Thanks a alot !